# DAX Cumulative Balances on Non Date Data

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I have a dataset `TransactionId`, `PolicyId`, `DebitnoteId` and `Amount`. I need to add cumulative/rolling balances for the policy and debit note balances. I have illustrated what the `PolicyID Rolling Balance` and the `DebitNote Rolling Balance` should be using colors to display items which made up the balances in the image below. I am new to DAX and not able to get the balances working without using the Date Functions.

[image: Data Set]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tried it out but here's something that you should give a try:

`PolicyID Rolling Balance = calculate(
sumx(values(policiID);[sum(amount) or lastnonblank(amount;0) I'm not sure :/]);
filter(all(Table) ; transactionID [<= or >=] MAx(transaticonID)))`

or with earlier function in a calculated column instead of max or in maxx (instead of max: `maxx(Table; transactionID[<= >=]earlier(transationID))`)

I hope at least it gives you a little hint which is working.
The DebitNote Rolling Balance should be done similarly (with DebitnoteId).
and another note instead of sumx one could use groupby function too, I guess. Like this:

`calculate(sum(amount); groupby(table; policyID); /\*filter like before*/)`

Oh. And one more thing I used ';' because I have this in my locale settings or somewhere. If it's underscored then you should use ','.

//sorry for this "Answer".  There's one answer I want to ask something but I can't, because I need some "reputation"...